# Radio input value on angular is string, can i get Number?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of radio buttons with days of the week, the value is weekday ID, a Number, but Angular transforms this value into string in my form group.

```
const currentHour = moment('08:00', 'hh:mm');
new Array(7).fill(null).forEach((acc, index) => {
  this.weekdays.push({
    day: Number(currentHour.weekday(index).format('d')),
    short: currentHour.weekday(index).format('dd'),
    long: currentHour.weekday(index).format('dddd')});
});
```

```
<div class="col weekdays" *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays">
  <input 
  formControlName="repeatEveryDay" 
  name="repeatEveryDay" 
  type="radio" 
  id="weekday-{{weekday.long | lowercase}}" 
  [value]="weekday.day" 
  [checked]="weekday.day == repeatEveryDay"
  >
  <label for="weekday-{{weekday.long | lowercase}}">{{weekday.short | uppercase}}</label>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get Number from the value or it's the way Angular works?

Comment: works fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js-dpgjv6?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

The value of the HTML input field is a string, not a number, despite the fact that it looks like a number. To convert a string to a number you can use `parseInt()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt